# TopCoder optimal choice algorithm from SRM 489 DIV 2 (500 pt)

Tags: java, c++, c, algorithm

I'm looking through random TopCoder problems in order to try and improve during competitions, I've come across one today that I'd like some input on.

**Problem Statement**

Teddy loves roses and Tracy loves lilies. They wish to plant these flowers in a large garden.

However, the only florist in town sells these flowers in packets which are represented by `vector<int>`s roses and lilies. The i-th packet contains roses[i] roses and lilies[i] lilies. Each packet can be bought only once.

Teddy and Tracy wish to buy some flowers and arrange them into a rectangular grid. This grid must be arranged such that each cell contains exactly one flower, and any two cells which share an edge must contain different kinds of flowers. Additionally, Teddy and Tracy must use all the flowers they buy.

Teddy and Tracy love square-shaped grids, so they wish to buy a set of packets such that they can arrange the flowers into the most square-like grid possible. More precisely, they wish to arrange the flowers into an R x C grid, where R and C are positive integers, such that |R-C| (|R-C| denotes the absolute value of R-C) is minimized. Return this minimum absolute value, or -1 if no valid arrangement exists.

**Definition**

Class:             `BuyingFlowers`

Method:            `buy`

Parameters:        `vector <int>, vector <int>`

Returns:           `int`

Method signature:  `int buy(vector <int> roses, vector <int> lilies)`

**Example**

{2, 4}
{4, 2}

Returns: 1

Buying all the packets to get 6 roses and 6 lilies, they can create a 3 x 4 grid with the following arrangement:

RLRL
  LRLR
  RLRL

The difference of the height and the width of this arrangement is 1.

**My thoughts so far**

So there were a couple of thoughts I've had about this problem so far that I figure might be important to solving it. Feel free to disregard them.

- Every rectangle created by the flowers will have an even number of roses and lilies on the perimeter. So the largest possible rectangle you could make with the flowers could be found by taking the smaller of the two in quantity, say if you have 6 roses and 4 lilies, since you only have 4 lilies the maximum size rectangle you could make would include 4 roses and 4 lilies.
- The challenge obviously comes when you consider that each cell of the rectangle must be filled with a flower, so you must find the "best fit" rectangle you can, given the number of flowers you have, that will satisfy both: providing enough "middle" cells for the rest of the flowers to reside in, and being as close to a square as possible.

I've looked at some of the solutions posted, however the code tends to be very obfuscated and optimized (in terms of writing it quickly) so it tends to be difficult to extract the concept the author had in mind for the solution.

I would appreciate any ideas, I'd love to learn about some ways to solve a problem like this quickly.

Comment: What are the restrictions on the number of packets?

Comment: @IVlad   
- roses and lilies will contain the same number of elements, between 1 and 16, inclusive.
- Each element of roses and lilies will be between 0 and 10000, inclusive.
- The total number of flowers in each packet represented by roses and lilies will be greater than 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to TopCoder, one of the most important sections of the problem statement is the Constraints section as this usually dictates what is possible within the time limit and what is not.

In your case, there are atmost 16 packets.Since the total number of possible subsets =2^16=65536 is very low, we can look at all the subsets of packets and decide which yields the best combination.

To do this use bit manipulation(in C++)

```
for(int i=0;i<(1<<16);i++)
{
 //i represents a subset
 for(int j=0;j<16;j++)
   if(i & (1<<j))
   {
    //j-th packet is present in subset
   }
}
```

Once you are given a combination of packets, can you tell how big a rectangle you can make?

Yes.

Hint:When you fix a lily at left top corner, how can you arrange remaining flowers?
**P.S**:There is only 1 way.
Similarly when you fix a rose at left top corner, there is only one way to fill the rectangle.

Once you pick this up, just iterate through all combinations of subsets and see which yields the minimum |R-C|.

Please ask if you have more questions.

Comment: I don't understand how there is only 1 way to arrange the flowers. For example if you had a subset with 6 roses and 6 lilies, you could arrange them 3x4

LRLR
RLRL
LRLR

Or you could arrange them 1x12 

LRLRLRLRLRLR

It seems like it is maybe necessary to construct every possible formation of rectangle that could be made with each subset and then save the one that was closest to square. But the simple solutions don't indicate that they do anything like that.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hint:Do you really need all possible rectangles for a combination of packets?

Answer (score 0):

Think about the following question: In a matrix N * M can I put more than half of the matrix lilies/roses?

Answering this question should let you finish the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow this hint. For some matrices, such as a 7x7, more than half of the flowers would be in the middle (25/49), and for others such as a 6x6 less than half of the flowers would be in the middle (16/36).

Comment: I didn't ask how many would be in the middle, but how many lillies would be in any point in the matrix. If you look at it you'll see it behaves like a chess board. You have at most half (half + 1 for odd number of cells) lillies or roses.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the examples at http://community.topcoder.com/stat?c=problem_statement&pm=11191, it looks like there are only two possibilities:

```
|number of roses - number of lillies| == 1, for odd R and odd C

or

number of roses == number of lillies, for even R or even C
```

If that were true, I would look for a way to find the number, `lillies + roses` (where `num lillies == num roses` or `|num roses - num lillies| == 1`) that can divide into the closest two integer factors (ideally the square root).

In the TopCoder examples, we have:

```
Example 0:     6 + 6 = 12, closest two factors 3x4
Example 1:     5 + 4 = 9, closest two factors 3x3
```

JavaScript example:

```
function closestFactors(n)
{
    var start = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(n))
    while (n % start != 0)
        start--
    return [start,n / start]
}

var roses = [1, 208, 19, 0, 3, 234, 1, 106, 99, 17],
    lillies = [58, 30, 3, 5, 0, 997, 9, 615, 77, 5]

function f(index, currentR, currentL, best)
{ 
    if (roses.length == index)
        return best
    for (var i = index; i < roses.length; i++) 
    {
        var cr = currentR + roses[i],
            cl = currentL + lillies[i]
        if (cr == cl || Math.abs(cr - cl) == 1)
        {
            var cf = closestFactors(cr + cl),
                current = Math.abs(cf[0] - cf[1])
            if (current == 0)
                return 0
            best = best < 0 ? current : Math.min(best,current)
        }
        best = best < 0 ? f(i + 1, cr, cl, best)
                        : Math.min(best,f(i + 1, cr, cl, best))
        if (best == 0)
            return 0
    }
    return best
}
```

Console output:

```
f(0,0,0,-1)
36
```

Comment: Actually |number of roses - number of lillie| == 1 for any rectangular grid for which the number of rows and the number of columns is odd